# Get reference to list item from context menu

Tags: android, android-listview, contextmenu

I would like to get the position in the list from the item that triggers the context menu. Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    c = contacts.get(position);
    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), c.getName().toString() + " Clicked " + (id + 1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), DetailActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("key", id + 1);
    startActivity(i);
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
    this.selectedPerson = contacts.get(info.position);
    MenuInflater mi = getMenuInflater();
    mi.inflate(R.menu.activity_context, menu);
    menu.setHeaderIcon(R.drawable.settings2);
    menu.setHeaderTitle(this.selectedPerson.getName().toString() + " - Options");
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch(item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.menu_edit:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Edit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        return true;
    case R.id.menu_delete:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Delete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        return true;
    case R.id.menu_fav:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Added to Favourites!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return true;
    }

    return false;

}
```

How exactly can I retrieve the position in a similar way to how I did in `onListItemClick()`? The reason being, I would like to call my data base adapter delete method which requires a row ID to execute correctly.

Many thanks!

Comment: Where do you call this  openContextMenu?

Comment: From within an Activity that extends ListView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

```
AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
```

in **onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)** to get item position of list adapter

```
@Override
 public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

 AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();

switch(item.getItemId()){
case R.id.menu_edit:
    Toast.makeText(this, "Edit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    return true;
case R.id.menu_delete:
    Toast.makeText(this, "Delete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    return true;
case R.id.menu_fav:
    Toast.makeText(this, "Added to Favourites!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    return true;
}

return false;

}
```